# What verbs best describe something appearing and disappearing alternately?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

I'm trying to describe the sight of houses on the mountain appearing and disappearing alternately because of the fog. What verbs best describe that?

Comment: Check out synonyms of "flash" and "blink" (and maybe "flicker").

Comment: It depends on whether the sentence starts with the **the fog** or **the houses**.

Comment: Another possible term (though probably reserved for brighter images) is "strobing".

Comment: Houses on mountains either *arise* from the fog or are *swallowed up* by it. Example sentence needed; answer to the title is *fade in and out*.

Comment: @Hot Licks: I think "strobing" would be reserved for something much faster.

Comment: ... _ethereal_ is as close as I can get to the whole concept with a single word

Comment: Catching glimpses of the houses through the fog. We don't have an ergative verb where we could say the houses were glimpsing through the fog.

Comment: A higherfalutin verb would be [*occult*](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+occulted&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS724US727&oq=define+occulted&aqs=chrome..69i57j0.6062j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) ;)

Comment: @PhilSweet , interesting, I'd only use occulting in an astronomy-like manner: that is to say for a solidish body of similarish size which, well, occults the object in question.  I wouldn't use it in a foggy, drifty situation.

Comment: _emerge_ and _retreat_ work well, if you also want to convey a sense of movement.

Answer (score 12):

[Mike Graham answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/522694/11040) made me imagine the houses inside the fog were appearing and disapearing reapidly.

Perhaps, the word "**fade**" captures better the idea that the houses disapear in the fog. Also, I do not think we need to be as metaphorical:

> As the fog rolled through, the houses fade in and out of view.

Comment: This is more of a fog behavior than "flicker" would be. Also, phase in and out of reality could also be a similar way to say this.

Answer (score 9):

You could use **flicker** somewhat metaphorically

> As the fog rolled through, the houses seemed to flicker in and out of existence.

Comment: thank you, I thought flicker is just used for light or flame

Comment: It's a good word, but to me a "flicker" is a quick event, so in this example (fog) I'm not sure it works.

Comment: This is a hugely confusing answer to a question that should just be on ELL !  OP now thinks that flicker can be used this way.

Comment: It… technically can be used in this way.  The first definition on hand does specifically reference _of light or a source of light_, however the second definition is generic: _make small, quick movements_.  Alternatives at different implied rates of change: pulse (if the change is progressive and rhythmic), blink (the change itself is rapid, but may persist), fade (slow, progressive rate of change), or phase, as in _phasing in and out of existence_, though the general definition is entirely suitable: _a distinct period or stage in a series of events or a process of change or development_.

Answer (score 8):

> **intermittently**
>   in a way that does not happen regularly or continuously; in a way that stops and starts repeatedly or with periods in between:

***Example sentence:*** The house appears ***intermittently*** through the fog.

Source:[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/intermittently)

Comment: Or to match the OP more closely, "Houses appeared intermittently through the fog".

Answer (score 4):

The expression '[They] V-ed in and out of vision' is often used.

Choices of verb include:

- move (very prosaic)
- phase (formal)
- shift (ordinary, and can sound unsubtle)
- stream (for rapid flickering)
- bob (on the comical side)
- drift (languid, perhaps overly so)
- ghost (evocative)  (perhaps the best choice)

All these variants may be readily found on the internet; adding definitions of the verb included would not really be helpful in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

I come up with "ephemeral" or "transitory" images of houses through the mountainside fog (or use one of their synonyms).

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/ephemeral

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/transitory

Answer (score 0):

Packaging up a comment of mine as an answer:

#### Flicker (flickering)

The first definition on hand does specifically reference *of light or a source of light*, however the second definition is generic: *make small, quick movements*.

English uses modifiers (adjectives) to add additional detail, however it also has multiple distinct words with slight variations of meaning for many concepts, including this one.  E.g. *ephemeral* (lasting a short time), *transitory* (temporary), or *intermittently* (at irregular intervals) could be used to modify the exact meaning of any of these verbs.

> *In the cold mist of the growing fog the houses flickered from view.*

#### Pulse (pulsing)

If the change is progressive, rhythmic, and typically cyclic (repeating), and typically of a short duration, e.g. a few seconds.

> *The lights of the houses pulsed from the unseen movement of the fog.*

#### Blink (blinking)

The change itself is rapid, but may persist afterwords in either the visible or invisible state.  Things may *blink into* (or *out of*) *existence*.  As a result of implied suddenness, something "blinking" away or to you is generally a surprising event.

> *Suddenly and alarmingly, the houses visible on the mountain blinked away, stolen by the fog.*

#### Fade (fading)

Representing a slow, progressive rate of change over time, usually in the "Human time-scale" of a second or more.

> *The homes intermittently faded from view, obscured by the fog.*

#### Phase (phasing)

As in *phasing in and out of existence*, though the general definition is entirely suitable: *a distinct period or stage in a series of events or a process of change or development*.

Phasing evokes a "(partial) shift out of reality", which may be… too strong.  Or possibly exactly right.  Depends on how sinister [the mist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mist_(film)) is.  ;)

> *As the fog rolled into the valley, the homes phased from visibility.*